# How can I convert a 1080p wmv video to a 720p video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, convert, hd-video

I have a 1080p wmv video that I'd like to convert to a lower quality (preferably 720p) video. I would like to keep the audio intact. How can I accomplish this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you used an ffmpeg tag I will use that for the answer.

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 output.mp4
```

Change the video quality by specifying a different CRF parameter. See the [x264 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

Comment: Option 'sameq' was removed. If you are looking for an option to preserve the quality (which is not what -sameq was for), use -qscale 0 or an equivalent quality factor option.

Comment: According to [ffmpeg's wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20(resizing)%20with%20ffmpeg), this can be as simple as: `ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf scale=-1:720 output.avi`

Answer (score 9):

Time has moved on a little since the original accepted answer for this question in 2012. Newer versions of FFmpeg would be better to use FFmpeg's 'scale' video filter.

I give an example below, using this filter, which also simply *copies* the audio track as you have requested:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv \
       -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -tune film -crf 22 -vf scale=-2:720 \
       -c:a copy \
       output.mp4
```

The `-tune film` option given above can be omitted or you could try `-tune animation` depending on the type of video clip you are using.

If you decided that you *would* like to transcode the audio a good choice would be to use the external library libfdk_aac as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv \
       -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -tune film -crf 22 -vf scale=-2:720 \
       -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k \
       output.mp4
```

This is certainly what I would do with a wmv file that I was scaling, you will find the results more than acceptable...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep intact all the audio tracks, subtitles and so on, you should use something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv \
       -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -map 0:4 \
       -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow \
       -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 copy -c:s copy \
       output.mkv
```

In this case, the input.mkv file has two audio tracks and two subtitles. You can specify all the audio tracks (or subtitles, or videos, etc.) one by one or as a single entity (as I specified for subtitles).

Hope it helps...

Comment: You don't need to specify each stream in the manner above: `-map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -map 0:4`

Instead, you can simply specify `-map 0` instead. This will automatically select all streams in input 0.

similar with audio copy codecs. The only codec options you need to specify are  `-c:copy -c:v libx264`. This means: "set all stream codecs to copy, except video which should transcode to x264."

Comment: Equivalent (showing parameter ordering): `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -vf scale=-1:720 -c:copy -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow output.mkv`